# call proceedure from sql server procedure from jasper report

Tags: java, sql-server, jasper-reports

Hello mates Iam trying to call sql server store proceedure from jasper report but iam getting this one error :- .sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : ReportTemplate
 i dont know what went wrong please help me on this.
from here i call procedure:-

```
<parameter name="param1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="param2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="param3" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="param4" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[Call P_SubLedger_Report($P{param1},$P{param2},$P{param3},$P{param4});]]>
</queryString>
```

And here is my java function:

```
public byte[] getSubledgerReport(String strtdate,String enddate,int acid, int subacid)throws Exception{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date parsedstrtdate = format.parse(strtdate);
    java.sql.Date stdate = new java.sql.Date(parsedstrtdate.getTime());
    Date parsedenddate = format.parse(enddate);
    java.sql.Date enddt = new java.sql.Date(parsedenddate.getTime());
    System.out.println("yaha aaya bhi"+stdate+" "+acid+" "+subacid);
    JasperReport jasperReport = null;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    try {
        parameters.put("param1", acid);
        parameters.put("param2", subacid);
        parameters.put("param3", stdate);
        parameters.put("param4", enddt);
       //String reportSource = "C:\\Users\\Subodh\\Desktop\\Teachers\\src\\DB\\Account\\AccountsReport\\newReport.jrxml";
        String reportSource = "C:\\Users\\subodh\\Desktop\\Bipin\\SSSML\\src\\java\\AccountReports\\SubLedgerReport.jrxml";
        jasperReport = (JasperReport) JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

        bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, parameters, conn);

    } catch (JRException e) {
        System.out.println("Error is kjsdhgjkshdgjkhg"+e);
    }
    conn.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. And just repost your whole jasper report.

and to check exception use printstacktrace. it will help you to know the exact problem.

oh sorry i missed this one

```
<![CDATA[{Call P_SubLedger_Report($P{param1},$P{param2},$P{param3},$P{param4})}]]>.
```

Comment: Thanks for rply but try what

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without ";" at the end? I'm sure it's not allowed at the end of the sql statement, not sure for call...